# datatables to change colour in second table

Tags: colors, datatables

I have two datatables showing side by side in my HTML as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
        "bFilter":  false
    });

} );

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example2').DataTable({
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
        "bFilter":  false

    });

} );
```

However, I would like that the second datatable ('#example2') to be displayed with a different background colour.

thanks

Comment: I have added the below but now both tables are being affected: `code` $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example2').DataTable({
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
  "bFilter": false
  
  
    });
$('#table.dataTable.stripe tbody tr.odd, table.dataTable.display tbody tr.odd').css({"backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white"});    
}
); `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your code to work, you have to change the selector to point only to `#example2`:

```js
$('#example2 tbody tr.odd')
    .css({"backgroundColor": "black", "color": "white"});
```

Note that you don't need jQuery for that, it's better if you do it with CSS only:

```css
<style>
#example2 tbody tr.odd {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

If you are using Datatables css, you can add stripes to a table with `class="stripe"` on the table, like the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/stripe.html) on their site:

```
<table id="example2" class="stripe">
```